# JMeter APDEX value showing as zero value in Apache JMeter Dashboard Report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In JMeter report, APDEX value is showing as Zero after Test Execution.

[image]

Could you please help us what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Hey, Yup it should show time sampler took but it wasn't showing. Could you please help me out on this one why it's showing as Zero.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too. The solution is increasing the sample size. If you look into the math of how [Apdex is calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apdex), the resulting index will be close to zero if all the params are too small.

```
Apdex = (SatisfiedCount + (ToleratingCount/2)) / TotalSamples
```

Short answer - increase your sample size, once I increased mine to 50, it started returning meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

my sample size was 700, but I was still getting 0 apdex for some samples (HTTPS requests). As an example, I have
checkout-600    700 samples,
checkout-600-0  1 sample,
checkout-600-1  1 sample,
and apdex for all three is zero. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is a follow up question and not an anwser